# How to split space between header and footer in Ryan fait stick footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Ryan fait sticky footer. it works well. but I need to split the space between header and footer like below

[image]

Fiddle here [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrdvW/1399/)

I have divs like

```
<div class='content'>
      <div class='firstdiv'>
      </div>
      <div class='seconddiv'>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want to display like red and pink boxes. The problem is I don't have height for `content` if have enough content (more than a screen) in `first div` or `second div` it needs to equally grow like `display:flex` but it doesnot have enough content fullpage needs to be cover. how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but the height will depend on the content. You can set the height manually but you also have to write styling for media queries.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -55px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
  height: 55px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}


.content{
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  //background-color:red;
}

.firstdiv{
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
.seconddiv {
  width: 75%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

      <div class="header">
         <h1>CSS Sticky Footer</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div class='content'>
          <div class='firstdiv'>
          </div>
          <div class='seconddiv'>
          </div>
      </div>
      
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>This <strong>CSS Sticky Footer</strong> simply stays put.</p>
  <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 Ryan Fait &mdash; <a href="http://ryanfait.com/" title="Las Vegas Web Design">Las Vegas Web Design</a></p>
</div>
```